# How can I find a specific GPG key for a CentOS 7 package rpm?

Tags: centos7, yum

I linked a machine through spacewalk to a few repo's including wandisco to get SVN to the latest version, as well as epel, and have ran into weird problems. Yum can't find a public key for updating `rubygem-json-2.0.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`, which it says is coming from the base package.

However I have the key at `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7`. I have been able to update all other packages explicitly like `yum update subversion` or `yum update perf python-perf`.

`rubygem-json-2.0.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` just doesn't want to play nice. I tried explicitly importing GPG keys like `rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7` and `rpm --import http://opensource.wandisco.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco`, but this doesn't change anything.

I understand `rubygem-json-2.0.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` is available from `http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/opstools/` (not just the base), but I am under the impression these use the same GPG key.

I am stuck right now. Yum says I need a key with an `Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 51bc2a13`, but I don't know what to do with this information.

Comment: To get the header signatures run this command `rpm -q --qf '%{HEADERSIGNATURES}' packagename`. To get the pgpsignature run this command `rpm -q --qf '%{SIGPGP}' packagename`. If you don't care about the signature and just want the package get installed, run `yum --nogpgcheck install packagefile.rpm`.

Comment: Note: The purpose of gpg is to ensure that rpm package file is not tampered. Use `--nogpgcheck` at your own risk.

Comment: Interestingly, I am getting `(none)` for header signatures. But I get the same for other packages that were able to update. I definitely don't want to avoid using gpg checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CentOS OptTools uses a different signing key.

Looking at [OPS Tools Repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/opstools/x86_64/common/), there is `centos-release-opstools-1-4.el7.noarch.rpm` that contains the following repository information.

```
# CentOS-OpsTools.repo
#
# Please see http://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/OpsTools for more
# information

[centos-opstools-testing]
name=CentOS-7 - OpsTools - testing repo
baseurl=http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/opstools/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-OpsTools
#
[centos-opstools-logging]
name=CentOS-7 - OpsTools - logging testing repo
baseurl=http://cbs.centos.org/repos/opstools7-elastic-common-testing/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Notice that `gpgcheck` is disabled and the `gpgkeyfile` is commented out. If this was installed in your OS, `yum` will not complain of the signature.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never guessed this. I installed the full centOS tree on my spacewalk server using `spacewalk-common-channels`, and I that opened me up to several channels I didn't know anything about. If I run into this again I'll know what to do. Thanks.